# How can I ask to an existing category?

Tags: categories

I want to echo the child category name. That works.

But how can I ask after an existing category, so that I have no `<h6>`-tag when I have no category?
Where is my mistake?

```
    <?php $category = get_the_category(); 
          $last_category = end($category);
          $category_name = $last_category->cat_name;
          $category_id = get_cat_ID( $category_name );
          $category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );

          if (is_category($category_name)) { ?>
          <h6 class="cat-child-name"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>"><?php echo $category_name ?></a></h6>

     <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Your question is not completely clear. Where is this code? On a single page? On a category archive page? What do you mean when you say "ask after an existing category ... when I have no category"?

Comment: Thank you for your response. This code is in my index.php in the main-loop. I want to output my child-category.  But when I have no category in an taxonomy, page or search.., then I don't want the h6-tag.

Comment: I think I need more template-files. I thought I didn't need more than an index.php with a little bit of if-coding. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check whether a certain post has a certain category, you need [`in_category`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/), so your test would need to be:

```
if (in_category($category_name))
```